# VBA possible to deactive autofilters before running actual macro

Tags: excel, vba

Is there a way to include some code in a macro that will allow to deactivate Autofilters, then run the actual macro and afterwards re-activating Autofilters?

1. Autofilter deactivation code
2. Original Macro Code
3. Autofilter re-activation code

I'm asking because my original macro does not work on the data with autofilters activated.

Comment: Do you need to remove filter entirely or show all data? Do you need to disable filters on a specific sheet(s) or in whole workbook?

Comment: I have a workbook containing several sheets and all of these sheets have Autofilters activated. My macro does not seem to work on the autofiltered sheets/workbook, so I was thinking to include a code to deactivated the autofilters, then making it run the macro code and reapplying the autofilters afterwards?

Answer (score 1):

```
ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False
```

Change ActiveSheet to your desired sheet/variable name

Comment: And where would I put this bit of code? Before the macro I'm trying to run? And what if the macro contains several sheets?

Comment: In Sl No. 1 & 3

Comment: "And what if the macro contains several sheets?" In that case post your whole code.

Answer (score 1):

**To disable filter on specific** `Worksheet`**:**

```
Workbook("WorkbookName").Worksheets("SheetName").AutoFilterMode = False
```

**To show all data (reset filter criterias) on specific** `Worksheet`**:**

```
If Workbook("WorkbookName").Worksheets("SheetName").FilterMode Then 
    Workbook("WorkbookName").Worksheets("SheetName").ShowAllData
EndIf
```

**To go through each** `Worksheet` **in** `Workbook`**:**

```
Dim ws as Worksheet
For Each ws in Workbook("WorkbookName").Worksheets  
    ws.AutoFilterMode = False '(can be replaced with .ShowAllData as in example above)  
Next
```

**To go through specific** `Worksheets`**:**

```
Dim ws as Worksheet  
For Each ws in Workbook("WorkbookName")  
    If InStr(1,"Sheet1Sheet2Sheet3Sheet4",ws.Name, 0) > 0 Then
        ws.AutoFilterMode = False
    EndIf
Next
```

If you work only with one `Workbook`, `Workbook("WorkbookName")` can be omitted.
If you need to refer to `Workbook` where macro is executed change `Workbook("WorkbookName")` to `ThisWorkbook`.
 **! Code below works ONLY if you used** `.ShowAllData` **!**
**To save filter criterias (execute BEFORE resetting criterias):**

```
Dim ws As Worksheet, i As Long, j As Long, x As Long, arrFCriteria(), Item As Filter
x = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
ReDim arrFCriteria(1 To x, 1 To 1)
i = 1    
For Each ws in ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    j = 1  
    If ws.FilterMode Then
        For Each Item in ws.AutoFilter.Filters 
            If ws.AutoFilter.Filters.Count > UBound(arrFCriteria, 2) Then ReDim Preserve arrFCriteria(1 To x, 1 To ws.AutoFilter.Filters.Count) 
            If Item.On Then  
                arrFCriteria(i,j) = Item.Criteria1  
            Else
                arrFCriteria(i,j) = 0
            EndIf  
            j = j + 1 
        Next  
    EndIf  
    i = i + 1
Next
```

Where arrFCriteria is 2d array with stored Filter Criterias.
Possible to restore filters using index (first dimension is index for `Worksheets()`, second dimension is index for `.AutoFilter.Filters().Criteria1`).
**To restore filters (add in the end):**

```
For i = LBound(arrFCriteria, 1) To UBound(arrFCriteria, 1)  
    j = 1  
    If Not ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(i).AutoFilter Is Nothing Then  
        For Each Item In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(i).AutoFilter.Filters  
            If arrFCriteria(i, j) <> 0 Then  
                ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(i).AutoFilter.Range.AutoFilter Field:=j, Criteria1:=arrFCriteria(i, j)  
            End If  
            j = j + 1
        Next  
    End If  
Next i
```

*Basicaly your code will look something like this:*

```
Sub MyMacro ()
    'Part0 (variable declaration, make sure to include those I wrote)
    'Part1 (saving criterias)
    'Part2 (loop through worksheets, reset filter)
    'Part3 (your macro code)
    'Part4 (restoring filters)
End Sub
```

Comment: What do the 'Go Through' codes do? Go through all worksheets and turn off the Autofilter? And ok to disable filters, but how do I turn them back on after my macro ran?

Comment: Yes, it goes through all `Worksheet`s. `ws.AutoFilterMode = False` removes AutoFilters entirely, only way enable them is how you did it in the first place (through other macro or manualy). But if you use `ws.ShowAllData` AutoFilter will persist but criterias will be reset.

Comment: @AntonioLopezRamirez Do you need to save AutoFilter state and restore it after running a macro?

Comment: I guess so yes. My worksheets show filtered data for the users, but when they click a button, the filters should be deactivated so my macro can run. And restore the filters afterwards.

Comment: @AntonioLopezRamirez Edited answer. Can you restore filters with this?

Comment: Ok, so to completely understand. I use the 'Go through' code with 'ws.ShowAllData' after the saving the criterias with the code you just provided? Then the filters will be reapplied after running my macro?

Comment: @AntonioLopezRamirez Not quite, it is only for saving filter criterias in an array, to restore filters themselves is whole another thing. I might come up with something if you need.

Comment: This coding has got me totally lost. I'm such a noob at this. Thanks for your help AntiDrondert.

Comment: @AntonioLopezRamirez Added another part, should work.

Comment: Ok and what is Part0 then? variable declaration? Part 1 is clear, Part2 is the Go through worksheets code that resets the filters, correct?

Comment: @AntonioLopezRamirez it is the line that looks something like this `Dim x as Long, y as Integer` etc. Part2 is resetting the filter, yes. Make sure you used `.ShowAllData` but not `.FilterMode = False`, otherwise macro won't restore filters.

Comment: @pnuts I understand, but it's easier to comprehend "Criteria" since syntax doesn't include "Criterion1" but "Criteria1".